# How to return true if one of 4 bools is true

Tags: c#

I am trying to realise a method, that returns true, if one of several bools is true.

```
bool a = false;
bool b = false;
bool c = true;
bool d = false;

private bool oneOfThem()
{
   return a && b && c && d;
}
```

This doesn't work. But how could I make this work?

Comment: or (||) is use for that purpose...

Comment: Downvotes because this could have been very easily answered with a quick search on the internet or _ANY_ book.

Comment: Same here, this could have been solved by a simple google search.

Answer (score 5):

Use `OR` (`||`) instead of `&&` operator.......

[|| Operator (C# Reference) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6373h346.aspx)

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool
>   operands. If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand
>   isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second
>   operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to
>   true or false.

Comment: I guess people really do like brief answers.. or vote by rep? :S

Answer (score 3):

```
private bool oneOfThem()
{
   return a || b|| c || d;
}
```

`&&` shortcuits on a `false` value.. `||` will continue evaluation and shortcuits on a `true` value

Answer (score 2):

This will return true if any of the input bools are true:

```
return a || b || c || d;
```

**Further Reading**

- [|| Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)

---

This will return true if exactly one of the input bools is true:

```
return new[] { a, b, c, d }.Count(x => x) == 1;
```

Or

```
return !new[] { a, b, c, d }.Where(x => x).Skip(1).Any();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you meant atleast one is true,

```
return a || b || c || d;
```

If you meant only one,

```
int truecount = 0;

if (a) truecount++;
if (b) truecount++;
if (c) truecount++;
if (d) truecount++;

return truecount == 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`||`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6373h346%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [`&&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) opetator..

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool
>   operands. If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand
>   isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second
>   operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to
>   true or false.

```
return a || b || c || d;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static bool a = false;
        public static bool b = false;
        public static bool c = true;
        public static bool d = false;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            oneOfThem();
            Console.Read();
        }
        public static void oneOfThem()
        {
            bool[] _bArr = { a , b , c , d };
            char[] _cArr = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
            int i = 0;
            foreach (bool _bool in _bArr)
            {
                if (_bool == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(_cArr[i] + " returned : True.");
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Homework done?

Comment: No. This was no homework. Simply forgot the logic